# Java&Android: onCreate вместо main

Tags: java, android

Вопрос, возникающий при переходе от изучения основы Java к программированию под Android.

Известно, что *минимальная* Java-программа должна содержать метод `main (String[] args)`:

```
public class Example
{
  public static void main (String[] args){

  }
}
```

И говорилось, что этот метод должен включать с себя *любая* Java-программа. Приложение под андроид же должно содержать в себе метод `onCreate`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
```

По идее, если Java-программа требует метода с именем `main` и параметром `String[] args`, то программа, состоящая из одного только метода `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`, должна быть непремлемой с точки зрения Java. Чем это объяснить?

Comment: Средой выполнения. Виртуальная машина на ПК загружает класс в память и вызывает метод `main`, а виртуальная машина мобильного устройства после загрузки вызывает `onCreate`.

Comment: это можно объяснить проще, _минимальная_ - не значит _обязательная_. Если следовать Вашей логике, то Spring - это вообще ни в какие рамки не вписывается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще то у андрода тоже есть метод main в ActivityThread. Но до него не добраться так просто

Comment: Понятно, то есть мы пишем приложение в какой-то специальной выделенной для этого области, а ядро от нас скрыто и в него не следует вмешиваться. Так?

Comment: Да, именно так и есть

Answer (score 1):

Даже в самой Java это не всегда верно. Сервлеты и Аплеты не имеют `main` метода.

Android использует язык Java, но рантайм отличается от обычной Java. Тут, вероятно, стоит сказать, что в Android то не обычный JVM, там Dalvik Virtual Machine, который ищет класс унаследованный от `Activity`, и который задан как LAUNCHER при старте в манифесте. Поэтому сравнение со стандартной JVM не совсем корректно.